# Giving subplots different orientations within fig Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib, dataset

Hello I am trying to plot 6 graphs with the subplot function in matplotlib however I would like to break these charts into different visualization styles. I would like to make 3 rows `a1` would be occupying the entirety of the 1st column `a2, a3` would occupy the 2nd column and `c1 , c2, c3` would occupy the 3rd column.

```
fig, (a1, a2,a3,c1,c2,c3) = plt.subplots(6)
fig, (a1, a2,a3,c1,c2,c3) = plt.subplots(6)
#Compounding Amount being plotted
a1.plot(x_indexes,Amount_list)
c1.plot(x_indexes, Non_compounding_list)
L =1
S = 1
x_long = []
x_short = []
for i in L_Amount_list:
    x_long.append(L)
    L+=1
for i in S_Amount_list:
    x_short.append(S)
    S+= 1
a2.plot(x_short, S_Amount_list)
a3.plot(x_long,L_Amount_list)
c2.plot(x_short,S_Non_compounding_list)
c3.plot(x_long,L_Non_compounding_list)
```

Comment: Looking for [`gridspec`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html)?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65265401/adding-two-smaller-subplots-to-the-side-of-my-main-plot-in-matplotlib-subplots/65268157#65268157) may already help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by BigBen, gridspec does the trick.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   # v 3.3.2

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(6, 3)
a1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 0])
a1.set_title('a1')
a2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:3, 1])
a2.set_title('a2')
a3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:6, 1])
a3.set_title('a2')
c1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2, 2])
c1.set_title('c1')
c2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:4, 2])
c2.set_title('c2')
c3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[4:6, 2])
c3.set_title('c2')
plt.show()
```

[image: gridspec]